# In Office365 Appointment can we integrate our service under room finder

Tags: office365, office365api, office365-apps

Is there any way through which we can integrate our room finder service with office365 OWA? Where user can search available rooms from our service

Answer (score 0):

You can have your add-in create a custom pane in the compose form of a meeting request to display your UI: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn482461.aspx.  Use either the Outlook Add-in API (https://dev.outlook.com/reference/add-ins/index.html), Outlook Calendar REST API (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/calendar-rest-operations) or Exchange Web Services (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp160952.aspx) to work with rooms and resources.

Comment: Thank you Eric for your response. But what I expect is there is one button in OWA (outlook web application) named Rooms, which is linked with room finder or resource setup .something like [this link](http://www.bu.edu/tech/services/comm/email/exchange/calendars/meeting/). We need to do this programaticaly in office365.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you want to do with your UI, but the only canvas available to you is a custom pane. Custom Ribbon buttons are currently not supported in OWA but should in the near future.